# Does anybody know how this thing triggers in android studio 3.5

Tags: android, android-studio-3.5

[image]
I take a snapshop from google io video,but I can't find this feature in android studio 3.5 .
here the video https://youtu.be/8rfvfojtRss?t=1679

Comment: not sure if the elevation feature is available in AS 3.5. Probably only in canary versions.

Comment: The feature is now officially released on the new stable version of AS 4.0. I've updated my answer!

Answer (score 1):

> Tools -> Layout Inspector

still there in 3.5

Comment: From the video I thought the user was referring to the elevation break-down feature and not the inspector itself. Is this available?

Comment: don't know is this feature is in AS 3.5 (can't check at this moment), but [check out this lib](https://github.com/JakeWharton/scalpel), may be helpful :)

Comment: sorry,I didn't ask clear 。I'd like to know about view layering，like ios reveal 
https://revealapp.com/

Comment: didn't heard about something similar in Android world, but seems like AS introduced this feature built-in :) (basing just on video linked in question, need to try)

Comment: good to know about the library. I didn't have time to watch the full video, maybe they even mention it there if the feature was meant to be included in 3.5 or if it's just part of the dev/canary channels, but even so, it means that as a feature is coming in the future.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE JUNE 2020**.
This feature is now available in the latest stable release of Android Studio 4.0.

[Example Use](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/layout-inspector-1f8d446d048)

---

This feature is available in Android Studio 4.0 which currently ships in the canary channels only. It is called 3D View and it's part of the new Live Layout Inspector. You can see it as part of the preview [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/#4.0-live-layout-inspector).

Note that:

> You can use the Live Layout Inspector only when deploying your app to devices running API level 29 or higher. You must also enable the feature by navigating to File > Settings > Experimental, and checking the box next to Enable Live Layout Inspector.